# Large table with many "exception" columns

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a large table, with 72 columns and tens of millions of rows of financial data, where more than half the content (40 columns actully) is *almost* always the default value. The table is mostly used by batch processes, and those columns contains informations about exceptionnal events that occur on this entity in edge cases and are managed mostly manually.

Our main concerns is that Liquibase updates now takes hours when we have to alter this table.

Would it make sense to replace this structure by a few tables linked togheter in 1 to 1 relationships ? I don't want to have tens of optionnal tables either because we're in a MySQL environnement and LEFT JOINs can get costly when there are too many of them. I know this would mean denormalizing the schema, as many tables would share the same identifier, but null columns all around is not a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is enough to answer this, but if they are rare events, then the question is how often you need to access them.

Breaking off rare events into a secondary table would certainly shrink your innodb tables and, depending on your access patterns, might generally speed up the system.  Of course if the data needs to always be accessed together then you have a problem and there may not be a free lunch there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would make sense to split the table and link them using a 1 to 1 relationship.

If you are worried too much about left outer joins then you could always insert a row all the tables with the main key and then update the columns depending on the business scenario. This way you can equi-join all the tables and reduce the performance impact.